# Choosing Google Earth Engine IDE

Tags: software-recommendations, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting to play with EE and I jumped right into the online web-based IDE for the Earth Engine JavaScript API (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground).

I see there is also a Python API but it seems much more complex to play with.

Also saw somewhre (https://youtu.be/m1ejxSi3l8s?t=418) Node.js might be used.

What are the alternatives?

In the online code editor it is not possible i.e. to edit two files at same time, which might be a limitation overcome by other approaches. I guess setting up Python environment will allow me to do that, may be to use Sublime Text as an editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use Jupyter Notebook or Lab, I have made a "code editor simulator". Initially I made two ways of using it, one via `folium` and the other one via `ipyleaflet`, but I have been updating only the latter because it's the only one I actively use. It can be a little annoying to install, I haven't pulish that, but if you get to it, you can do:

```
import ipygee as ui

Map = ui.Map()
Map.show()
```

and that is it, in any other cell you can do:

```
Map.addLayer(image, visparams, name)
```

and many other methods.

To install it, aside of having GEE python API installed, you need: ipyleaflet, folium, pandas, PIL, pygal, numpy, requests, pyshp, so before installing it, do:

> pip install pyshp pygal pandas pillow numpy requests folium ipyleaflet

then you can install it

> pip install ipygee

You can find the source here: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/ipygee

And report issues here: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/ipygee/issues

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your scripts with any IDE you want as long as you include git into your workflow.

All the scripts you see are based in git repositories (see [GEE docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground#script-manager-scripts-tab)):

> The Scripts manager stores private, shared and example scripts in Git repositories hosted by Google.

You can see an overview of all the repositories you have access to at https://earthengine.googlesource.com/.

Editing multiple scripts at the same time is possible. Checkout the respository, edit with the IDE of your choice and commit the changes.

> Repositories can be accessed using Git, so you can manage and edit your scripts outside the Code Editor, or sync them with an external system like GitHub.[...] For some Git operations, you may need to create authentication credentials by going to the Generate Password link at the top of the earthengine.googlesource.com page.